# identity comparison - comparing same object returns false

Tags: python

Could someone answer below (Output is from IDLE or check on python shell - python 2.7). For 1),2) and 3),4) I am doing exactly same operation but getting different results.

1) >>> a=0

2) >>> a is 0

True

3) >>> a=0.0

4) >>> a is 0.0

False

5) >>> 0.0 is 0.0

True

why 4)  is False?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: Since the answers don't properly account for it, let me note that (IIRC), you should expect 5) to be false too -- it only turns out to be true because of an optimization in the parser. I don't have a reference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because an optimization in `CPython` that for any integer between `-5` and `256` returns a reference to an already existing object, meaning `a` is a reference to `0`, so they have the same `id()`. There is no such optimization for floating point numbers like `0.0`, so a new object is created on assignment (meaning that `id(a) != id(0.0)`).

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html

Answer (score 1):

The python `is` operator is used to test if two variables point to same object.

From the documentation:

> The operators is and is not test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object.

For eg.

`a = 0.0`

if you do `b = a` and then follow it up with `b is a`. It will return True.

Now if you do `a = 0.0` and `b = 0.0` and then try `b is a` it will return False, because now a and b are two variables pointing to two different objects.

Comment: I just did `a = 0.0; b = 0.0` and then `b is a` said `True`.

Comment: Well you're not doing what I said. I didn't say I did `a = 0.0` and then did `b = 0.0`. I said I did `a = 0.0; b = 0.0`. Try *that*.

Comment: @StefanPochmann did you mean this http://imgur.com/a/rYKCL? If not, can you provide a sample?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I guess you're using IPython and it does things differently. Try it in a Python shell, like the OP apparently did (as indicated by the `>>>`). I do get `True` there.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Noted! and thanks. I am pretty used to IPython and do not tend to used python shell. Also, it does return `True` there. Something for me to ponder why :)